# IIS, XP, SSL vs. KeepAlives

Tags: iis, ssl, windows-xp, keep-alive

I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place. I'm developing on XP using Studio 2005/IIS. Thus far, this has been problem free for me, until today.

I needed to add an SSL cert so I could finish development for a part of the site that runs in SSL using sessions that are only allowed in secure mode.

So, I install the cert and fire up studio in debug mode/F5 and hit a secure page with the browser. The pages load some images, not other images when using https and keep alives are enabled. Turn off keep alives, and all page images load on every request, but studio won't attach the debugger griping about an auth failure. Turn keep alives back on, studio will debug just fine but images go screwy.

I'm sure this is the connection limit imposed upon IIS in XP. Is there a work around for this madness? Flip flopping the checkbox to get work done is killing my sanity. Vista and/or Server Operating Systems aren't a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the MaxConnections value to something higher:

```
C:\Inetpub\scripts>adsutil.vbs get W3SVC/MaxConnections
MaxConnections                  : (INTEGER) 10
C:\Inetpub\scripts>adsutil.vbs set W3SVC/MaxConnections 100
MaxConnections                  : (INTEGER) 100
```